# callback_query working more than once in inline keyboard

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Below is the code.
When my code runs for the first time it works like a charm, but when I again input the URL and click on any of the buttons it shows me 2 pics (1 pic is from the previous result), and for 3rd time it shows 3 pics (2 pics are from the previous result)  and so on.
So, when I again input the URL, it should only work once.
With the below screenshots, you can understand my problem better.

[When codes run for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B122Z.jpg)

[When it runs again with the same URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9NjD.jpg)

[When it runs for 3rd time with different URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNJyW.jpg)

So, to solve the issue what is the best possible option

```
require('dotenv').config();
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const token = process.env.TOKEN;

const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {
    polling: true
})
bot.onText(/\/yt/, async (message, match) => {       //ontext takes regex
    if (match.input === "/yt") {
        await bot.sendMessage(message.chat.id, "No input")
    } else {
        const url = match.input.split(' ')[1];
        if (url.match(/v=(\w|-|_)+/g)) {
            var idOfVid = url.match(/v=(\w|-|_)+/g);
            idOfVid = idOfVid[0].slice(2);
            fetch(`${accessYoutubeApi}${idOfVid}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(async (data) => {
                    titleOfVideo = data.items[0].snippet.title;
                    channelOfVideo = data.items[0].snippet.channelTitle;
                    if (url != undefined) {
                        if (/(www.youtube.com)/gm.test(url)) {
                            await bot.sendMessage(message.chat.id, `${titleOfVideo}
${channelOfVideo}
Select the photo size :`, {
                                reply_markup: {
                                    inline_keyboard: [
                                        [{
                                                text: "120x90",
                                                callback_data: "default"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                text: "320x180",
                                                callback_data: 'medium'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                text: "480x360",
                                                callback_data: 'high'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                text: "640x480",
                                                callback_data: 'standard'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                text: "1280x720",
                                                callback_data: 'maxres'
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                            })


                            bot.on("callback_query", function callback(callBackQuery) {
                                callBackData = callBackQuery.data;
                                thumbnails = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails;
                                if (callBackData == "default") {
                                    bot.sendPhoto(message.chat.id, thumbnails.default.url, {
                                        caption: "120x90"
                                    });
                                } else if (callBackData == "medium") {
                                    bot.sendPhoto(message.chat.id, thumbnails.medium.url, {
                                        caption: "320x180"
                                    })
                                } else if (callBackData == "high") {
                                    bot.sendPhoto(message.chat.id, thumbnails.high.url, {
                                        caption: "480x360"
                                    })
                                } else if (callBackData == 'standard') {
                                    bot.sendPhoto(message.chat.id, thumbnails.standard.url, {
                                        caption: "640x480"
                                    })
                                } else if (callBackData == 'maxres') {
                                    bot.sendPhoto(message.chat.id, thumbnails.maxres.url, {
                                        caption: "1280x720"
                                    })
                                }
                                /*bot.answerCallbackQuery(callBackQuery.id)
                                    .then((e) => {
                                        if (callBackData.command == idOfVid) {
                                            bot.sendMessage(message.chat.id, "Wait for few seconds, may take some time");
                                            bot.sendPhoto(message.chat.id, thumbnails[callBackData].url)

                                        }
                                    })*/
                            })
                        } else {
                            bot.sendMessage(message.chat.id, `Invalid URL
If you are providing the URL of youtube video make sure while pasting the URL before /yt don't write any character.
If you have provided the perfect URL, please try again.`)
                        }
                    }
                })
        } else {
            bot.sendMessage(message.chat.id, 'Invalid URL')
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This is what happens in the console for the 3rd case in above pic

https://i.imgur.com/MVDSoHv.jpg

Comment: Looks like you register a new on callback_query event handler every time the onText is called. Try clear any existing callback_query event handlers before registering a new one.

Comment: Ya I am getting you, but how can I achieve that ?

Comment: The telegram bot extends the EventEmitter class by the looks of it so it should just be a call to `bot.removeListener("callback_query")`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved half of the problem.

Comment: What half of the problem did it not solve?

Comment: Now I am unable to download the image more than once, because as soon as I click the callback query is executed and then it's removed. So i can download a specific size pic once only . After that again I have to give command /yt to download the another size pic. Sry for replying it late.